# How can I update a calculated column using Sharepoint Designer 2013?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I'm new to Sharepoint Designer and I'm having trouble to get a task done.

I've created a list and each item of this list should have a specific code.

Here's an example:

> **2014DEM/000023**.

I got this format done by creating a column named "Code" based on another columns value and inserting the following formula:

```
*=CONCATENATE(YEAR(TODAY());"DEM/";FORMAT([ID];"000000"))*
```

This formula works fine, but the problem is that when a new item is being created, its ID is zero, so when the user saves this new item, the code column value for this value returns

> **2014DEM/000000**.

If I try to edit the Code column formula, don't change anything, and only click the OK button, all the Code values will be updated to the value it was supposed to be.

Does anybody know how I can solve this problem? Could I update the column values using Sharepoint Designer Workflow?

Obs.: I'm using Sharepoint Designer 2013.

Comment: Have a look at my answer to similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24014806/calculated-sharepoint-column/24015049#24015049

Comment: You should either close this or add a detailed accepted answer ...